# Cannot burn or use Ubuntu images on Mac

Tags: installation, mac, dvd

I'm trying to get a version of Ubuntu running on my old Intel Mac. However, my computers think all of the disc images I've tried so far (downloaded from Ubuntu.com, I've tried 32-bit versions of 12.04, 12.10, and 13.10) are invalid (when I try to open the disc image I get an error "no mountable file system") and when I burn them using Disk Utility (following the instructions [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-mac-osx) precisely), they make unreadable discs.

There are already a few questions around this issue here, but none of them give any information about what to do (most answers assume the questioner isn't aware of the burn instructions or hasn't followed them; I have).

I've seen some mention of "Mac-specific" images, but I only see 64-bit Mac images and the computer I want to install it on (a 1.83GHz Core Duo from ~2006) is far, far too old for that.

How can I burn a working install DVD?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the reason might be, the guide you mentioned does not describe what you actually want to do. It describes how to burn a generic image onto a CD/DVD on a mac, but to be used with an intel PC - not a mac.

A mac has a different boot mechanism, called (U)EFI. Some PCs also boot from UEFI media, but all still support legacy bios booting mechanisms, which is still widely used.

To boot from a cd/dvd using a mac, be sure of this:

- Use and burn a 64bit image. 32bit will not work.
- Boot while holding down the options key

I haven't tested it myself, but the [this seems to be most promising guide](http://www.rodsbooks.com/ubuntu-efi/).